# Symlink for files in nested folder

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, symbolic-link

I have a media server with files hosted on a set of networked hard drives (all of the files are in symlinks to allow them to be caught by my dlna server)

How can I symlink (`ln -s`) all of the "cover.jpg" to the same dir that the covers are in but as a link called poster.jpg for all the nested folders located within `/mnt/1TB2/TV/`?

I did try this code and it will list them all with this line

```
find -L /mnt/1TB2/TV/* -name 'cover.jpg'
```

It ends up listing them all, but will not allow me to use that in a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $(find -L /mnt/1TB2/TV/* -name 'cover.jpg')
do
    ln -s $file poster.jpg
done
```

However I'm not the best at bash scripting (seriously little to no experience) I think it has something to do with the whitespace in the folder names but I'm not certain.

**Note:**
There are a lot of files and folders in this drive but the main map is as follows

```
=TV SHOW NAME (CONTAINING SPACES)
=-cover.jpg
=-trailer.mov
=-SEASON 00
=-+cover.jpg
=-+TV SHOW - 0X01 - EPISODE NAME.MKV
=-SEASON 01
=-+cover.jpg
=-+TV SHOW - 1X01 - EPISODE NAME.MKV
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
find -L /mnt/1TB2/TV/* -name cover.jpg -execdir ln -s cover.jpg poster.jpg \;
```

`-execdir` moves to the directory of the file, and executes `ln -s cover.jpg poster.jpg`.

---

There are two main problems with your script:

1. `for file in $(find -L /mnt/1TB2/TV/* -name 'cover.jpg')`

   This will break on whitespace. E.g. a file path that contains `SEASON 01` will be split at the space.

   It's usually best to avoid handling filenames in a shell script, instead using `find -exec` or `find -execdir`. But if you really need to, the most thorough method I'm aware of is

   ```
   while IFS= read -rd '' filename; do
       ...
   done < <(find ... -print0)
   ```

   ... which is a mouthful.
2. `ln -s $file poster.jpg`

   Since there is no change of directories, the symlink will be created in the directory where you run the script.

   And this will also split `$file` on whitespace. You should always quote your variables: `"$file"`

Comment: Thank you so much, this actually worked perfectly for what i needed (also thanks for explaining the use of -execdir , i didnt even know that was a thing to use)